# How to use np.arwhere with multiple conditions?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to pick indices of 1,2,3,12 and 13 with np.argwhere or np.where.In both cases following code is not working. Is there any way to do this using these two commands or should I use it twice instead of using & operator?

```
`a= np.array([1,2,3,4,10,12,13])
b = np.argwhere((a<4) & (a>10))
c = np.where((a<4) & (a>10))
print(b)
print(c)`
```

Comment: `and` logic doesn't make sense here. How can an element be less than 4 and greater than 10? You need `or` logic like so: `a[(a < 4) | (a > 10)]`

Comment: `(a<4) & (a>10)` or what ever you use, is evaluated first, creating a boolean array.  `where` (and from that, `argwhere`) just finds the indices of the True values.

Answer (score 7):

```
In [31]: a= np.array([1,2,3,4,10,12,13])                                        
In [32]: a                                                                      
Out[32]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4, 10, 12, 13])
```

The 2 conditions individually:

```
In [33]: a<4                                                                    
Out[33]: array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False])
In [34]: a>10                                                                   
Out[34]: array([False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True])
```

Join them with logical or:

```
In [35]: (a<4) | (a>10)                                                         
Out[35]: array([ True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True])
```

`where` is a tuple (size 1 because there's 1 dimension):

```
In [36]: np.where((a<4) | (a>10))                                               
Out[36]: (array([0, 1, 2, 5, 6]),)
```

That tuple can be used directly to index `a`:

```
In [37]: a[_]                                                                   
Out[37]: array([ 1,  2,  3, 12, 13])
```

`argwhere` gives the same indices but in a 'vertical' format:

```
In [38]: np.argwhere((a<4) | (a>10))                                            
Out[38]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [5],
       [6]])
```

It may be easier to visualize, but isn't so useful for indexing (unless you do it iteratively).

With the logical and, the result is an empty index - no value meets both conditions:

```
In [39]: np.where((a<4) & (a>10))                                               
Out[39]: (array([], dtype=int64),)
```

Comment: For anyone unfamiliar with `ipython`, the underscore in the answer refers to *"the output of the previous command"*, see **Output caching system** here https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where` :

```
c = np.where((a < 4) & (a > 10),a, a)
c
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4, 10, 12, 13])
```

Comment: This `c` is the same as `a`, not what the OP wanted.